# What would be the lowest cost approach to a low power, up to months-long timer?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, timer, 555

I'm looking for a starting point.  I wish to make a very small circuit (SMD, something like 2cm x 2cm PCB) low cost (translating to hopefully well < $1 at production).  The circuit would provide a timer configurable (via programming or by varying external components as necessary) from as little as hours to as much as 3 months.  Accuracy is NOT a priority, although 10% or better should be a non-critical goal.  It would run on battery and need very low consumption as this may need to operate for months without charging or user attention.

At first I thought of a 555 but quickly realized it wouldn't be suitable for times longer than several minutes.  A microcontroller feels like overkill to me.  I mean, ALL it needs to do is keep a loose semblance of time and then output a digital high of some sort.

Is a micro the way to go?  If so, any particular suggestions?  If not, other ideas?

Simpler the better. Very low power (ideally in the low microamp range), small size... cheap.

edit:  I want to stress that eventual goal is production.

Comment: What do you wish to drive with this timer? You say: "microcontroller = overkill", I say: digispark attiny85 on ebay. It costs about $1 delivered at home, needs no external components other than a 5V power source which will cost another $1. And arduino... huh, easiest thing to program on earth. "Hardest" part will be to learn how to enter low power mode (about 200uA range). It has fair precision and you can stack counters to create an almost unlimited timer length.

Comment: Thanks.  Arduino would not be appropriate for production.  I'll look at that Attiny, but at first glance it appears expensive.  Over $1 at volume from reputable suppliers.  I'd like the full circuit to cost under that at volume.  200uA at low power also is probably too high, although with a minimal duty cycle, it probably averages much lower.  There are much lower powered micros. The Attiny814 looks perfect but  isn't available yet.  In any regard, I take your point is that micro is your vote?

Comment: Believe me, you want a microprocessor. Otherwise, cobble something together with old logic chips. 32kHz oscillator. Digital comparator. Countdown timer with preload.

Comment: @mkeith  I believe you.  I'm hoping for something simpler that I've missed (like some new 555-esque thing that is appropriate that I've never heard about)... otherwise its a matter of finding the RIGHT micro.  I've been at it for days and finding that balance of power, size, cost and availability has been frustrating.

Comment: Attiny runs a lot lower current in power-down mode 10uA @ 3V... and you can use the watchdog timer to wake it up and use that as your heart-beat.

Comment: "Finding that balance of power, size, cost and availability has been frustrating." Isn't it always...

Comment: You could probably even use a pic. Keep it in sleep most of the time with the watchdog timer running.

Comment: Pic10f200 sounds like it fits the bill, 40cents in volume, 100nA sleep current. Small in a 6 pin sot23.

Comment: R u sure about the 814 not being available yet? http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATTINY814

Comment: Everyone is right about using a micro -- an MSP430 is probably the lowest power device available -- order of \$1\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ with the RTC active. They are also cheap. But not as cheap as you seem to want. A discrete option may be possible, but I fear leakage may be an enemy here. (*Months* would seem difficult.) A micro can do this all day long. There are some under 50 cents each in modest qtys, though their RTC power consumption is almost always higher than MSP430.

Comment: @Colin__s The standby current is that low, but there is no RTC running.

Comment: @bcsteeve The MSP430G2210 is about 40 cents in 2000 qty. They will burn about \$500\:\textrm{nA}\$ at \$2.2\:\textrm{V}\$ with the LF oscillator running (the VLO) and they can start up the DCO to full speed (multi-MHz range) in about \$1\:\mu\textrm{s}\$. I don't know of anything that gets close. They will run on less than the leakage spec of a lithium button battery. And they are easy to program with excellent tools.

Comment: @jonk, you're right about the PIC, I overlooked that.

Comment: @Colin__s No problem. I use the PICs all the time and prefer Microchip because of the way they treat me as a customer. No company is better to me. But TI's (grabbed up from a German company) MSP430 is much lower powered and the tools are very nice (I use assembly, so even the IAR tools are free to me.) 16-bit ALU not unlike a PDP-11, as well, which makes assembly rather easy.

Comment: @jonk didn't know that, thought it was a TI development! Looked it up - MSP430 came out 1993 - that's actually a pretty long time back

Comment: @MarcusMüller I believe it was originally designed with an eye to household power metering. I wrote a page about the processor more than 15 years ago -- outdated now but still here: http://www.infinitefactors.org/jonk/msp430.html -- and I do really like the processor a lot. For 16-bit or less, I mostly use either PIC (started with them in 1987, I think) or MSP430. For 32-bit, I use M4k (I go back to 1985 with MIPS R2000, so long experiences) and of course ARM. (Not counting x86.)

Comment: If this is a large quantity product you may want to consider COB tech instead of a packaged device too. That can save you a good bit per unit though you have to trade off the extra manufacturing costs. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-chip-on-boards-are-made

Comment: @Trevor if it were THAT large quantity, I wouldn't be asking questions on SE  :)

Comment: @Trevor (earlier), yes, I'm sure about the 814 not being available.  If you click "buy" on that same page you'll see it is expected in June.  No distributors have it.  If I knew for a fact it would be on time, I could live with June... but I did that with the Atmega1634 a few years ago and they blew their "available by" date by 9 months.

Comment: @everyon... thanks for the great input!  The MSP430 looks pretty great.  I'm confused by the lack of concise information vs. the huge number of variants, so that's a bit of a turn off (some MSP430's don't allow for ISP, some do?  Wth.  Give it a different number if it is that different of a product).  So I'm happy about jonk giving me a specific model and I'll check that out.  I'll check out the other chips too.  I think I have my answer anyway:  micro is the way to go.  THANK YOU.

Comment: @bcsteeve There is also the MSP430G2230 if you want the ADC, instead of a comparator. Either can be used to measure a resistor value, if you want to use that to configure the time, though whether or not to good enough resolution is another issue. Since cheap is good, I think you want to figure out how to use the comparator version for that and avoid paying for the ADC. Use the IAR tools, by the way. VERY easy to use. VERY good. ZERO COST if you use the "kickstart" version. Installation is trivially easy, too.

Comment: @jonk  this is going to be laughable, but I've been searching for HOURS this evening just trying to figure out how to program an MSP430.  I see tons of references to the (once cheap but now not as such) "launchpad" but I can't tell which launchpad works with which devices.  I found various programmers but they say things like "works with MOST MSP430".  I can't imagine the logic TI has behind naming everything the same and then supporting each one so differently.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to paying < $5 for a programmer (AVR, PIC, STM) and being able to find definitive documentation in 5 minutes.  Lol... I'm just frustrated and being lazy.

Comment: @bcsteeve I use several. But in this case I'd recommend getting the MSP-EXP430G2. It's $10. (I got mine for less and free shipping.) You might wait until 4/30/2017 to make your purchase. TI often makes INCREDIBLE deals on that day (like half price, free shipping, etc.) for the MSP430. By the way, it may also be helpful to look for TI's MSP430 FeRAM based controllers -- look them up sometime. Not for this application because they are more expensive. But FeRAM is interesting and worth a look, anyway.

Comment: @jonk   lol... it took me a second to get the significance of the date.  I was thinking, "why?  celebrating Hitler's death?  Seems odd."   I'm tired.

Comment: @bcsteeve hehe. I should have explained it, I suppose. Glad you figured it out. Anyway, you can get something now and then buy more on 4/30 to get the discounts and make up the difference! ;)  (I buy them by the several dozens because I give them away to students!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a microcontroller with RTC. I have used once an STM32L011 for pretty similar application (99,99% sleep, do something occasionally). It has a suspend mode and RTC. You can turn everything off (including RAM) and leave the RTC and wake up function running. In that mode I have measured consumption of 1,7uA (at 3V). There are some battery-backed registers in the RTC block, so you can keep state of your application across resets/wakes.

Be also careful with other components. I have used [this probe](http://www.cmicrotek.com/uCP.htm) to measure the standby current and when I added one tantalum capacitor the current jumped to 2,7uA, so sometimes adding an extra component **may double your power consumption**.

Comment: A 32-bit seems vastly overkill!  I've never worked with STM, but they do seem to have low-power in their corner.  I'll take a closer look.  That particular model is more expensive at volume than I'd like.  TY for the lead.

Comment: It may look like an overkill until you realize that it is the cheapest option :)

Comment: 32bit vs 8bit doesnt mean much as far as overkill or not.  The 32bits are competitive in many ways.  Each year someone else has the lowest power mcu and each year they all claim the lowest power mcu.  Been playing with the same stm32l family, am either not getting a good measurement or cant get below 20uA but still with a 2000MaH battery that is...11 years.  I think I have it waking up to check the timer some number of times a second.  blinking the led every few seconds is the bigger deal depends on what else you want to drive as to battery life.

Comment: these and other vendor parts are easy to sample and program, just get some and try them...

Answer (score 3):

You could use 4040 or 4060 CMOS multi-stage dividers, they were designed for long timing tasks, back in 1900-and-frozen-to-death. Very low power, especially at low speed.

The 4060 has a built-in oscillator, 14 binary stages, but omits a few LSB outputs. The 4040 has 12 binary stages with all outputs brought out, but no oscillator. Perhaps use both in cascade for timing to 3 months.

You can set the oscillation frequency for fine control of the time, the repeatability should be well within your 10%, but nowhere near that of a clock. Select the output for coarse period control.

Or you can use a microcontroller, and get all the switches and other stuff you need built in. PIC or AVR would do, they both have low power modes and more processing power than you need, I personally prefer AVR because you can prototype with Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be for CMOS, such as the CD4521 run at a low frequency. One of these with its oscillator running at 1kHz (a simple RC network should be sufficiently stable) has an output period of up to around 4 hours. You don't specify how you intend to select the output period but further dividers, such as a CD4040, will be required. That should give a series of selectable outputs over the range of periods you require, and meet your other requirements as well.